# perl output image from a remote source

Tags: perl

So I am trying to use a script to simply proxy some images through it. the images are hosted on a remote server so I need to download the image and display it. This is the code I have so far:

```
    binmode STDOUT;
    print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n";

    #DB commands to find the image

    my $file = $image_folder."/".$file_real."0000.jpg";
    print $file;
    my $html0 = get($file);

    print $html0;
```

For some reason this does not work, when I change the header to html and print html0 it shows the data but when I change the header to jpeg or png it fails to compile!

Comment: Need two return characters in your header: `print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n";`  Also, should be sure that you're loading your file in binmode as well.

Comment: thats it, it was just that extra `\n` :) so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need two return characters in the [header](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CREATING-A-STANDARD-HTTP-HEADER):

```
print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n";
```

Also, should be sure that the file is loaded in [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) as well.