# Output image in HTML formed with perl

Tags: html, image, perl, cgi

I tried the first solution explained in [Perl CGI display image to browser from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851799/perl-cgi-display-image-to-browser-from-file) topic.

Everything works perfect... except for the fact that, instead of displaying the image in the browser, it displays a lot of strange characters (something similar as when I open the image in notepad.

This is the code I am using:

```
#perl CGI code lines before
select(STDOUT); $| = 1;   #unbuffer STDOUT
print "Content-type: image/jgp\n\n";

open (IMAGE, '<', '/absolute_route_to_image/logo.jpg');
print <IMAGE>;
close IMAGE;
#rest of HTML code, displayed in a print statement in perl
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: show the code that you are using

Comment: Most likely you haven't set your Content-Type right.  Check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523718/perl-output-image-from-a-remote-source

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is the part of my code where I am trying to display the image (excuse me if I put the code wrongly, I recently joined this great community, so still entry level):

#some more code lines before
select(STDOUT); $| = 1;   #unbuffer STDOUT
print "Content-type: image/jpg\n\n";

open (IMAGE, '<', '/root_to_image/logo.jpg');
print <IMAGE>;
close IMAGE;
#After this, I start the construction of the rest of the HTML script from
#perl

Answer (score 0):

> rest of HTML code

An HTTP response can include *one* resource. You can't spluge out a pile of raw JPEG data in the middle of an HTML document. The browser is processing HTML, not a JPEG.

In general, you need to have the browser make a second HTTP request to get the image (with the URL specified in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element.

It is possible to express the entire resource in the form of a URL using the `data:` scheme though. The [`URI::data` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::data)  can help you generate them.

> ```
> print "Content-type: image/jgp\n\n";
> ```

Also, the content type for JPEGs is [`image/jpeg`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image). Not `image/jgp` and not `image/jpg`. You are seeing how browsers treat unknown mime types.